# Rails 5 API: custom hidden responder that would process value returned by the action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I have rails 5 based api app, using `fast_jsonapi`
and after a while I observe that all most all my actions are having one common pattern

```
  def action_name
    @some_object.perform_action_name # this returns @some_object
    render json: ControllerNameSerializer.new(@some_object).to_h
  end
```

I do not wish to write the last `render` line here and it should work, for that I want that the returned value by the action should be processed by any **hidden** responder like thing, Serializer klass can be made out looking at controller name.

Perhaps this could be achieved by adding a small middleware. However at first, I find it not a good idea/practise to go for a middleware. In middleware, we do get rendered response, we need a hook prior to that.

I would imagine like

```
class SomeController ...
  respond_with_returned_value

  def action_name
    @some_object.perform_action_name # this returns @some_object
  end
```

Any suggestions?

Note, do not worry about error/failure cases, `@some_object.errors` could hold them and I have a mechanism to handle that separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketched out...

```
class ApplicationController < ...
  def respond_with_returned_value
    include MyWrapperModule
  end
...
end

module MyWrapperModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.public_instance_methods.each do |method_name|
      original_method_name = "original_#{method_name}".to_sym
      rename method_name -> original_method_name
      define_method(method_name) { render json: send(original_method_name) }
    end
  end
end
```

Seems like there really should be some blessed way to do this - or like someone must have already done it.

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a clue to make it very similar one - my sample here https://gist.github.com/amolpujari/37dc624afea9d12ed2e0c807417a861d. I wont apply this all over right away, I will wait to see how my app grows, at the same time I see this forces a bit to follow certain things like no custom err handling, always setting up errors to AR object errors, and always deal with AR objects, relations or json like data etc. Controller looks really really thin now

Comment: That's let runtime hacky - which is probably good.  Things I worry about:
* Using this in production mode with values instead of blocks might yield constant values - not dynamic ones.
* You might want to make some of those methods private/protected instead of public.  Shouldn't matter, but better to be safe.